# Send report to local printer from JasperReports Server through URL

Tags: jasperserver

I'm trying to call a report and send to local printer from a web app using JasperReports Server. There is a lot of documentation out there outlining output formats like PDF but I'm not finding anything on printing. I'm calling the report with url like

http://myhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&j_username=joeuser&j_password=joeuser&param=1&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports&reportUnit=%2Freports%2Fmyreport&output=pdf

This downloads a pdf, is there anyway to get this to send to local printer?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
w3m -dump_source  "http://www.goo.com:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&j_username=joeuser&j_password=joeuser&param=1&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports&reportUnit=%2Freports%2Fmyreport&output=pdf" | lpr
```